# Where is jetty-all-server for 9.x?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

We're upgrading the jetty version from 8.x to 9.x in our project.

It was `org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.7.v20120910`

But for 9.x, I can't find `jetty-all-server` anymore, instead, I found `org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:9.2.7.v20150116`, notice the package name has changed to `jetty-all`

So I wonder is `jetty-all-server` stopped at 8.x and it changes the name to `jetty-all` at 9.x? Or there will be new `jetty-all-server` at 9.x in the future?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but jetty 9 was released almost two years ago, I don't think they will be releasing any other artifact for this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `jetty-all-server` for Jetty 9.

Seeing as there are so many components of Jetty that are, in fact, conflicting with each other, the whole aggregate concept is really not viable any more.  The introduction of npn/alpn for the spdy/http2 support also makes the aggregate impossible due to bootclasspath requirements.

The choices for the jetty group with aggregates are to either make every permutation of aggregates (currently standing at over 400 different combinations) or none.

We left `jetty-all` as a helpful one for use in the jetty-documentation for the getting started / introduction to Jetty phases, but it is **absolutely inappropriate for production use**.

Use a build tool (maven, gradle, ivy, buildr, grape, sbt, leinengen, eclipse, intellij, netbeans, make, shell script, etc..) and add the components from standard jetty to your project.  You can even make an aggregate of your own.