# jetty-all source jar (9.3)

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Migrating from Jetty 9.2.x to 9.3.x I do not find anymore the jetty-all-9.2.9.v20150224-sources.jar ( https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/9.2.19.v20160908/ ) for 9.3.x

Is there any way to retrieve such a JAR for 9.3.x ?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see prior answers about `jetty-all`.

- https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28110675/775715

Know that `jetty-all-*.jar` is **only** for the command line examples in the jetty documentation.

If you are using any variation of `jetty-all-*.jar` in your project or build, then you are using it incorrectly.

If you are using the `jetty-all` `<dependency>` in your build, then your build is currently using the individual downstream dependencies from that `pom` declared coordinate.  Each of those dependencies have their own `sources` classified attached artifacts (and `javadoc` classified too) for you to download and access the source from.

**Example Maven project pom**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-all-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.11.v20160721</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Which will produce the following list of dependencies

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jetty-all-demo 1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ jetty-all-demo ---
[INFO] com.test:jetty-all-demo:jar:1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:pom:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-deploy:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaspi:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.security.auth.message:jar:1.0.0.v201108011116:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-rewrite:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-quickstart:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-client:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-server:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-common:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-hpack:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-client:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.mail.glassfish:jar:1.4.1.v201005082020:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.activation:jar:1.1.0.v201105071233:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.164 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T05:41:17-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/485M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each and every one of those dependencies has its own `sources` jar.

We've tested NetBeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ, they all can access / download those `sources` jars from the global central repository system.  Each of those 3 IDE's can also use `jetty-all` from any of the popular build systems (maven, gradle, ant+ivy, buildr, grape, grails, sbt, etc)

Maven and Gradle even have available tooling to download those dependencies and/or sources jars for you.

**To download default artifacts (normally jars) to target/dependency/**

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

**To download sources artifacts to target/dependency/**

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources
```